# Dispatching first runs undefined and then resolves in Redux Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to use Redux thunk to feth data from an API and into redux, but I run into a problem where redux dispatches twice, once with an undefined action, and once with the actual action. i tried changing my action, changing my reducer and my thunk but nothing seems to work. I've succesfully used redux thunk before and never ran into this issue.

My thunk function

```
export const fetchCountryInfo = () => {
return async (dispatch,getState) => {
    const response = await Axios.get(https://api.covid19api.com/summary)
    console.log(response.data)
    dispatch({
        type:'updateCountryData',
        payload:response.data.Countries
    })
}
```

}

My reducer:`const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

return action.payload
}`

Dispatching the action

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();


useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCountryInfo())
  });
```

[Thunk dispatching with the actual text first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGI7n.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchCountryInfo())
}, []);
```

Add `[]` with no deps, it will dispatch only once

Comment: I tried that, but this is a different problem, see the link. The first time it dispatches, it returns the function itself as the action.